# Heroku setup that would support 3-5 Million visitors per hour

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, heroku

A post on the Reddit front page will gather as many as 30 million to 50 million page views. All of that within 24 hours, and perhaps only within 10 to 12 hours.

So, there could be 3 to 5 million visitors per hour. Say 3.6 mil per hour, that's 1000 visitors/second.

Our website: ruby on rails + postgres app that allows user registration (devise) and renders a simple page with a YouTube video embed.

Assuming an unlimited budget, approximately what Heroku setup would be able to handle the traffic? What's the likely bottleneck (db connections? concurrent requests?)

```
For example: 
10 standard 1x dynos + Standard 2 Postgres DB
or
2 performance M dynos + Premium 2 Postgres DB
```

Comment: What is your app's average response time? Does your Homepage serve static content or how many database call does it generate? What conversion rate (page views vs signups) do your expect? IMO this question cannot be answered without deep knowledge about your app and its characteristics.

Comment: @spickermann 30ms average response time. Home page serves basic static content (bootstrap css, js), signup conversion rate is less than 5%. Just wondering if anyone has any rough estimates/experience with heroku serving this amount of traffic.

Comment: Why don't you server your assets and the static homepage via CDN? That would remove load from the dyno. Then you only have to think about new users.

Comment: I wish I'd have to worry about such problems. CDN as spickermann said and don't forget to double double check your database indexes. As a redditor, why not push that youttube video (though even that will have a hard stand against our friend imgur) and put big links to your website? Reduces your visitors but those clicking through are more likely to sign up.

Comment: You are saying 3,6mil (3.600.000) per hour. It's around the 250.000 page-views per hour (clicks etc.) meaning even LESS visitors (a visitor views more then 1 page in general).